# Установка php 7 рядом с php 5

Tags: php7, php5-fpm

Возможно ли установить `php 7` рядом с `php 5` как `HHVM` например? Просто чтобы проверить работоспособность кода? Буду рад если подскажите полностью схему установки.
Используется `php5-fpm`, то есть `php7` тоже должен быть `fpm`
Заранее благодарен

Comment: Попробуйте поднять на виртуальных машинах.